# finding nearest square number with a limit

Tags: python, square

Hey so I want to write code for finding nearest square number less than or equal to a certain number(x). I've tried the following:

```
m = 0 
base = 0 
while m <= x:
   if m > x:
      break
   m = base**2
   base += 1

print(m)
```

This, however, gives the nearest square right after the number x despite putting the break since a m > x has already been assigned to m. how i do stop the loop before m > x?

Comment: Loop will automatically break, no need for if condition

Comment: Of course, you can do this without a loop: `math.floor(math.sqrt(x)) ** 2`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Came here to say the same thing! Good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if m > x` is redundant. The loop body will only be entered if `m <= x` is True, and if that's True, `m > x` never will be, so that `break` should never run.

To answer your question though, without knowing more about the math, I'd just introduce a second variable `prev_m`, then use that:

```
m = 0
prev_m = m
base = 0 
while m <= x:
    prev_m = m
    m = base**2
    base += 1

print(prev_m)  # Then use prev_m instead
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this using `math` module:

```
import math 
y = math.sqrt(x) #find the square root of x
if y.is_integer() == False: #check y is not a whole number
    print(math.pow(int(y),2)) # find the square root of the nearest whole number to y
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are based on calculating one square too many and then using the previous one.
But is there a possibility to know if the next square will be too big, **without calculating it**?

```
m = 0
base = -1
while base*2 + m < x:
    base += 1
    m = base**2

print(m)
```

Disclaimer: Just a fun answer to think about why this works.